# Why does importing a csv in Python or R double size

Tags: python, csv, pandas, kaggle

This probably is a well known answer....but why does a file (csv) that is 11GB turn into more than twice that size when imported into Python (Pandas) or R?

The data in question is from [a Kaggle competition](http://www.kaggle.com/c/criteo-display-ad-challenge/data) which is 11GB when unzipped (the train file). When I load it into python or R, it takes up more than twice that space. I have 32 GB of RAM on windows (with ~29 free when I load the file) and I nearly run out of space.

In Python:

```
import pandas as pd
train=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\train.csv")
```

In R:

```
train<-read.csv(file="C:\\train.csv",header=TRUE)
```

Comment: I assume due to data types, try forcing to be 32bit floats

Comment: Is there a way to do that easily?

Answer (score 3):

## Serialized data and data in memory differ in structure

Serializing data to disk (e.g. to CSV file) is rather simple task, it only has to support writing data down and reading it out in predicable way. The only rule to follow is using well defined format.

On the other hand, data loaded into RAM for processing often grow for couple of reasons:

- all numbers use the same size in bytes and to fit all expected values, number of bytes is bigger then necessary for most of the numbers.
- on 64 bit versions of programs is minimal amount of allocated memory limited - from the bottom, so even the simplest data occupy more data than necessary just for addressing reason given by OS
- there are often supporting structures (e.g. for hashes/dictionaries, there is sort of index around)

Anyway, it might happen, that in memory data are more efficient than some poor serialization format, but as you have experienced, this is not your case.